# android set a view to invisible and back to visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a FrameLayout I want to disappear it on a button click and make it reappear on a button click
I tried this to disappear and it worked great

```
background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                background.invalidate();
```

but when I tried to get it back using the below code it didn't work.

```
background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                background.invalidate();
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: what is validate() ? I don't even see it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: I believe he meant `invalidate()`, which won't really help since that's what you ask...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the thread on which you are executing these

Comment: and it's not neccessary to call invalidate in this situation, invalidate is called when you want the view's onDraw to be called, so it only makes sense on custom views that override onDraw / draw / dispatchDraw

Answer (score 1):

just have a look at this [example](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html). This may help you!
And I think the method  `invalidate()` invalidates the view (after invisible the view)and so it's not reverting back(invisible to visible).